# user_photos facebook permission doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a web project and integrating Facebook login for users.
And I am going to add some permissions, which allow my web to get access to user information when login by Facebook.
I added

```
$permissions = array(
    'scope' => 'user_friends, user_photos, email, user_status, user_website, user_videos'
);
$loginUrl    = $helper->getLoginUrl(new_fb_login_url(), $permissions);
```

Then I try to login by a facebook account and it works with user_friends, email and it asks user to allow access to. But didn't with user_photos as well as some other, it didn't ask for photos access. Been trying searching for hours on this.

Can anybody help me on this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Are you testing this with an account that has a role in the app (admin, developer or tester)? Otherwise you of course need to submit the permission for review, before you can ask normal users for it ...

Comment: did you read about login review in the docs? it may be the problem.

Comment: thanks @CBroe I have figured out the problem. I have to ask user_photo permission for my facebook app. I am going to do that.